# CriteriaQuery selectDistinct with @EmbeddedId generating invalid SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-primary-key

I have a `CriteriaQuery` I'm building where I need to get the number of rows but when I have a composite key defined using `@EmbeddedId`, I get an error from the database when Hibernate tries to run the SQL:

```
14:35:16,356 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SQL Error: 909, SQLState: 42000
14:35:16,357 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

The SQL Hibernate has generated is similar to the SQL below where the members of the embedded ID are in the distinct clause:

```
select
    count(distinct tab_.COLUMN_A,
        tab_.COLUMN_B,
        tab_.COLUMN_C) as col_0_0_ 
from
    SOME_TABLE tab_ 
where
    -- ...
```

A shortened version of my Java code is:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<SomeEntity> root = query.from(SomeEntity.class);
countQuery.select(builder.countDistinct(root));

// ... then add predicates

long totalRowCount = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Is there a different (proper) way to get a count using an entity with an @EmbeddedId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue in Hibernate. 
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9814